# Remove Min and Max values in Array of Type Double

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I need to remove the MIN and MAX values in an array (of type Double)

Im trying to get a Mean of 3. The array is always having values added to it (its a timer)
I need to get the last 5 values in the array (the latest times) and then remove the min and the max value, i then need to add the remainging 3 values together and divide them by 3.

```
    if oldSessionTimes.count > 5 {
        var mo3WorkOutSuffix = mo3WorkOut.suffix(5)
        let removeMin = mo3WorkOutSuffix.min()
        let removeMax = mo3WorkOutSuffix.max()

        print("Min = \(removeMin!)")
        print("Max = \(removeMax!)")

        print(mo3WorkOutSuffix)

    }
```

Comment: `let removeMin = mo3WorkOut.min()` This doesn't remove, it just give which one was the minimum number. Also, you are doing it not on the last 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort first then remove the elements

```
var array: [Double] = [1.0, 2.3, 1.5, 1.8]
                array.sort()
                array.removeFirst()
                array.removeLast()
                print(array)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array: [Double] = [1.0, 2.3, 1.5, 1.8]
array = array.sorted().dropFirst().dropLast() // [1.5, 1.8]
```

Comment: Yes I did check, I thought it was obvious that it has to be reassigned to the array again.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

in php the array sorting by value ...    

 $num=array(23,32,45,12,15);    
 sort($num);   //this is for sorting by value in ascending order    
 array_shift($num);  //this is for removes first element by the array    
 array_pop($num); //this is for removes last element by the array    
 print_r($num);  //finally print the sorted array and it removes first and last element of array    

 output:[15,23,32];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your code, why does it solve the problem etc. So others can understand the answer easily.